# How to recursively call out another function x number of times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a working recursive function which I have to recursively call out in another function "depth" amount of times.

Working function:

```
def apply_dragon_rules(string):
    """
    Write a recursive function that replaces characters in string.

    Like so:
        "a" -> "aRbFR"
        "b" -> "LFaLb"
    apply_dragon_rules("a") -> "aRbFR"
    apply_dragon_rules("aa") -> "aRbFRaRbFR"
    apply_dragon_rules("FRaFRb") -> "FRaRbFRFRLFaLb"

    :param string: sentence with "a" and "b" characters that need to be replaced
    :return: new sentence with "a" and "b" characters replaced
    """
    if not string:  # if the string is empty
        return ""
    elif string[0] == "b":  # if the string start with b, replace it with a
        return "LFaLb" + apply_dragon_rules(string[1:])
    elif string[0] == "a":  # if the string start with b, replace it with a
        return "aRbFR" + apply_dragon_rules(string[1:])
    else:  # else, add this character and go to the next one
        return string[0] + apply_dragon_rules(string[1:])
```

The function in which I have to recursively call out the working function "depth" times:

```
def curve(string, depth):
    """
    Recursively generate the next depth of rules.

    Calls apply_dragon_rules() function `depth` times.
    curve("Fa", 2) -> "FaRbFRRLFaLbFR"

    :param string: current instruction string
    :param depth: how many times the rules are applied
    :return: instructionset at iteration 'depth'
    """
    if depth == 0:
        return ""
    elif depth == 1:
        return apply_dragon_rules(string)
    else:
        return depth * apply_dragon_rules(apply_dragon_rules(string))
```

Expected output:

```
curve("Fa", 2) -> "FaRbFRRLFaLbFR"
```

My output(2x the expected output):

```
curve("Fa", 2) -> "FaRbFRRLFaLbFRFaRbFRRLFaLbFR"
```

I was able to produce a correct output by making function curve (although, that is not a recursive solution and only works if the "depth" is 2):

```
return apply_dragon_rules(apply_dragon_rules(string))
```

Any ideas how to implement depth into the curve function so it works as intended?

Comment: depth is numeric so curve is just repeating the result of `apply_dragon_rules(apply_dragon_rules(string))` depth times, rather than applying the function depth times (you always apply it twice for depth > 1).

Comment: the else condition should be `return curve(apply_dragon_rules(string), depth - 1)` if you want to implement this recursively

Comment: Wow, so i was actually remotely close haha! Thank you very much kind sir! Wish I could choose your comment as  the best answer...

Answer (score 2):

The second function doesn't need to be recursive. You can simply loop to achieve that effect in general.

```py
def curve(string, depth):
    if depth == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        for i in range(depth):
            string = apply_dragon_rules(string)
        return string

print(curve("Fa", 2) == "FaRbFRRLFaLbFR") # Test result
```

Comment: I would, but I needed the solution to be recursive :/ Have a +1 instead, thank you kind sir and all the best in life to you!

Comment: @Crimson I see, thanks and to you too! If this is an assignment then have at it, but for future reference, many problems like this have easier iterative (looping) solutions.

Comment: I am well aware, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to pass the *remaining depth* as a parameter and make the base case of the recursion that this remaining depth is zero.

...which you already did halfway, but what's missing is to actually make the recursive call and pass the remaining depth—which is *one less* than the current depth:

```
def curve(string, depth):
    if depth == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return curve(apply_dragon_rules(string), depth - 1)
```

Comment: The first function doesn't accept the depth parameter you pass in your answer. What did you mean?

Comment: He meant : `return curve(apply_dragon_rules(string), depth - 1)`

Comment: Somehow I thought that you wanted to change `apply_dragon_rules` and wasn't aware of the other function. Nevermind.